# flutter app compile error:too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given. leading = IconButton(

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I had my flutter app working fine but started getting multiple errors on compile. I have also tired a new project with boiler plate code but it also throws the same bunch of errors. Any help would be great. I have tired upgrading and cleaning the project with no success.

```
flutter: The following _CompileTimeError was thrown building AppBar(dirty, state: _AppBarState#61196):
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/material/app_bar.dart': error: line 399 pos 29:
flutter: file:///Users/bradmurray/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart:399:29:
flutter: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
flutter:         leading = IconButton(
flutter:                             ^
flutter:         leading = IconButton(
flutter:                             ^
flutter:
[Screen shot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUO2Y.png

I am also getting this error form time to time:

   Compiler message:
file:///Users/UserName/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/icon_button.dart:87:20: Error: Duplicated parameter name 'icon'.
    @required this.icon,
                   ^^^^
file:///Users/UserName/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/icon_button.dart:82:25: Context: Other parameter named 'icon'.
  const IconButton(Icon icon, {
                        ^^^^
file:///Users/UserName/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:3726:23: Error: Duplicated parameter name 'text'.
  Row(Text text, Text text, {
                      ^^^^
file:///Users/UserName/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:3726:12: Context: Other parameter named 'text'.
.......
```

Answer (score 2):

An `IconButton` requires that you pass in an `Icon` widget and an `onPressed` call back.

Comment: I dont have any Icon buttons in my code.  This error is from the boil code start up program

Comment: can you share your source?